# Order by relationship count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph which looks like this:

```
User->Friend->Area 
|             (Which area does this friend live in)
------------->Area<-Friend<-Other users
              (Which area does this user live in)
```

If i like to find all areas where i dont have friends, i do this

```
start user=node(reference)
match user-->friend-->area<-[r?:HAVE_A]-friend<--user
where r is null
return area
```

Works great!

But how to order the results so i get the area which have the most users first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are getting the correct areas returned but want to organize them by the count of users.

In that case you need a [`WITH`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html) clause to get the users, [`COUNT`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-aggregation.html#_count) them,  and an [`ORDER BY`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-order.html) to sort them:

```
START user=node(reference)
MATCH user-->friend-->area<-[r?:HAVE_A]-friend<--user
WHERE r is null
WITH area 
MATCH area<--users
RETURN area, COUNT(users) as cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```